# Display different pop up windows for different image buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was making this project website and I came across this idea of making a pop-up box to show the products' description. As I was making the pop-up message box which would appear on clicking different images, I saw that it was showing same messages for different products even after giving different description for each one of them. I don't know JavaScript much but some code must be added there I guess.

Here is the code-

```js
$(".modal-trigger").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  dataModal = $(this).attr("data-modal");
  $("#" + dataModal).css({"display":"block"});
  // $("body").css({"overflow-y": "hidden"}); //Prevent double scrollbar.
});

$(".close-modal, .modal-sandbox").click(function(){
  $(".modal").css({"display":"none"});
  // $("body").css({"overflow-y": "auto"}); //Prevent double scrollbar.
});
```

```css
.modal,
.modal-box {
  z-index: 900;
}

.modal-sandbox {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

.modal {
  display: none; 
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: rgb(0,0,0);
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  overflow: auto;
}

.modal-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 920px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  animation-name: modalbox;
  animation-duration: .4s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0,0,.3,1.6);
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 20px 40px;
  background: #546E7A;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.modal-body {
  background: #ECEFF1;
  padding: 60px 40px;
}

/* Close Button */
.close-modal {
  text-align: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes modalbox {
  0% {
    top: -250px; 
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0; 
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes modalbox {
  0% {
    top: -250px; 
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0; 
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.modal-trigger, button {
  top: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.modal-trigger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: ease .2s;
}

button {
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  outline: none;
  color: #333333;
}

.modal-trigger:hover {
  padding: 20px 60px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="services-container container-fluid">
        <div class="container sess-in-cont">
            <div class="session-title row">
                <h2>Our Services</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse venenatis magna odio, eu vehicula augue suscipit ac. Pellentesque quis dui lorem. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="sess-row row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="serv-det">
                        <figure class="imghvr-fade">
                            <img src="assets/images/services/s1.jpg" alt="">
                            <figcaption>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse venenatis magna odio, eu vehicula augue suscipit ac. Pellentesque quis dui lorem. Vestibulum sed blandit diam,
                                <a href="#" class="modal-trigger" data-modal="modal-name">Modal open!</a>
                            </figcaption>
                        </figure>
                        <h6>Telecom</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal" id="modal-name">
                    <div class="modal-sandbox"></div>
                    <div class="modal-box">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <div class="close-modal">&#10006;</div> 
                            <h1>ex1</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Product 1 Description 1</p>
                            <p>This is first product description</p>
                            <br />
                            <button class="close-modal">Close!</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                  
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="serv-det">
                        <figure class="imghvr-fade">
                            <img src="assets/images/services/s2.jpg" alt="">
                            <figcaption>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse venenatis magna odio, eu vehicula augue suscipit ac. Pellentesque quis dui lorem. Vestibulum sed blandit diam,
                                <a href="#" class="modal-trigger" data-modal="modal-name">Modal open!</a>
                            </figcaption>
                        </figure>
                        <h6>Networking</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal" id="modal-name">
                    <div class="modal-sandbox"></div>
                    <div class="modal-box">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <div class="close-modal">&#10006;</div> 
                            <h1>ex2</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Product 2 Decription 2</p>
                            <p>This is second description</p>
                            <br />
                            <button class="close-modal">Close!      </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</body>
```

This is a template I picked up from codepen.io.

Answer (score 1):

By the error it shows, you can be sure that you didn't include jQuery.
The `$` is a class of jQuery ,so if it's not defined, you don't have jQuery.

If you don't know how to include jQuery, insert this code before your script tag:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"/>`

**EDIT PART:**

To bind a `click` event with a  `function()` you can use the `$.on(‘event’, function())` or the `$.click(function())`

Here:

```js
 (‘#imageId’).on(‘click’, popup());  
 (‘#imageId’).click(popup());
```

Comment: Actually there is no error in my file, from where I have copied this. It is working fine and jquery is inserted.

Comment: idk, it may be because it is not in the snippet, because I only ran the snippet.

Comment: why don't you use jquery and bind each click with a popup function?

Comment: is your code for _one_ image or for _all_

Comment: it is for many images. how can i use jquery to bind each click??

Comment: sorry for the late answer, you can bind clicks in jquery using $.on('click', _function_) or $.click(_function_)